# Export 2D-array as image using Labview IMAQ

Tags: labview

i would like to export a two dimensional data array as an image using labview IMAQ Libs. It seems like the array to image function can only handle greyscale, whereas save image only works for RGB. The export format (jpg, png, ...) is not of high priority. Is there any way to solve this?

Attached an image of my data flow. [image]

Comment: Can you please provide with the code with the array values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use IMAQ ArrayToColorImage.vi instead of IMAQ ArrayToImage.vi
[image]

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work for me. Is there a minimum of data-elements the Array needs to have?

Comment: Providing the code with the array is complicated, but it basically a read of measurment data. The array is 256x256 in size, values are in the range of 0.10 - 0.15.

Comment: Values should be integers. 0.10 - 0.15 will be converted to integers upon input. This will make values all 0s. png image with all 0s would be 256x256 plain black image like this:https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7e8068iulwiix5/picture6.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, i tried it again with integers, but it doesn't work. I get an Error from the ArrayToColorImage function every time. Can you provide me with some code where the export worked?